# Stack over flow Error occurring when an internal API called from spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

A Spring boot web application running in tomcat server suddenly encountered a stack over  flow error. The error occurred seems to be due to spring-boot recursively trying to add authentication header to the spring boot  to an internal API call

```
        headers.set('Authorization', headerValue);

    ResponseEntity<JsonNode> response = null;

        AccountView reqData = new AccountView(Account, getAccountState(Account));

        HttpEntity<AccountView> request = new HttpEntity<>(reqData, headers);

        response = restTemplate.postForEntity(apiUrl + "/v1/fetch/clients", request, JsonNode.class);
```

#### LOG

```
 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1: 2021-02-01 11:44:27,260 INFO
 com.sample.service.impl.FetchDataServiceImpl [http-nio-8080-exec-4]
 update api start  

 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1: 2021-02-01 11:44:27,278 INFO com.sample.service.impl.FetchDataServiceImpl
 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] Update client 

 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1: 2021-02-01 11:44:27,279 INFO com.sample.service.impl.FetchDataServiceImpl [http-nio-8080-exec-4]
 sending an fetch data api to get client details 

 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1: 2021-02-01 11:44:27,292 ERROR
 org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter

 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] Forwarding to error page from request
 [/api/businessAccount/busi_00000000000048] due to exception [null] 

 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1:  java.lang.StackOverflowError: null 

 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1: 
 org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.convertKey(LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.java:283)

 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1: t
 org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.containsKey(LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.java:135)

 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1: 
 org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils$MultiValueMapAdapter.containsKey(CollectionUtils.java:507)

 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1: 
 org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.containsKey(HttpHeaders.java:1535)

 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1:  org.springframework.http.client.support.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.java:81)
 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1:  org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92)
 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1:  org.springframework.http.client.support.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.java:84)
 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1:  org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92)
 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1:  org.springframework.http.client.support.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.java:84)
 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1:  org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92)
 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1:  org.springframework.http.client.support.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.java:84)
 Feb  1 11:44:27 dev-server-1:  org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92)

.......
```

The AccountView.java file

```
public class AccountView {
    private String parentId;
    private String accountName;
    private String companyName;
    private String state;

    public AccountView(Account account, String state) {
        this.parentId = account.getClientId();
        this.accountName = account.getAccountName();
        this.companyName = account.getCompanyName();
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    
    
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.parentId = id;
    }

}
```

The issue reoccurred whenever an internal API was called again from Application. After restarting the application the issue stopped occurring. Can someone please tell me why such an issue occurred and possible solution for this issue.

Comment: Can you please show us the AccountView.java file (implementation)

Comment: @Noxies 
I have added  AccountView.java .

Comment: Hm, I thought it could have had something to do with internal self reference .. That caused the most json convertions from java objects for me